# How to remove "This field is required." after choosing an option in select?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm creating a form and I made a validation so it has a `field is required` text popping up when you click the submit button.

It works pretty well but, it has 1 problem. When it pops up, and I select an option from the select tag, the `field is required` text doesn't hide automatically, but when it's an input text and I type something in it, the text hides automatically.

```js
$('#name').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value != "") {
    this.removeAttribute("required");
    this.required = false;
  }
});

function Validate(_id) {
  $("#form_validation").validate({
    rules: rules,
    highlight: function(input) {
      $(input).parents('.form-line').addClass('error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(input) {
      $(input).parents('.form-line').removeClass('error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-float">
  <div class="form-line">
    <select class="form-control show-tick" name="name" id="name" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden="">-- Please select --</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-float" align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="insert" class="btn btn-lg large" id="data">
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the submit button?

Comment: I added it now @Gerard

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the attribute novalidate on the SELECT tag?

Example:

```
<select class="form-control show-tick" name="name" id="name" required novalidate>
```

Comment: it doesn't do anything :/

Comment: @Nytraxaqw, could you post a print with the message? The message you're getting is from html or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are typing the right `selector` in this snippet:

```
$('#elemschool').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value != "") {
    this.removeAttribute("required");
    this.required = false;
  }
});
```

change `elemschool` to `name` as the `id` in the select 
`<select class="form-control show-tick" name="name" id="name" required>`
is equal to `name`

so basically it will be like below:

```
$('#name').on('change', function() { // here is the change
  if (this.value != "") {
    this.removeAttribute("required");
    this.required = false;
  }
});
```